# What's wrong with my CASE? (types...cannot be matched)

Tags: sql, postgresql

> `CASE WHEN table1.text IS NULL THEN table2.numbers
>   ELSE table1.text
>   END AS newcolumn`

When running this code I keep getting this error: 
**ERROR:  CASE types character varying and integer cannot be matched**

You would think that this would not cause problems since I'm creating a new column within my query. I'd also like to point out that I'm using an old version of PostgreSQL if that helps.

Comment: "You would think that this would not cause problems since I'm creating a new column within my query" Err... Why would you think it wouldn't cause problems? What type do you expect the column to have?

Comment: I'd guess it would become varchar, I'm not creating a table, it's just a query to pull out information.

Comment: You need a `CAST` as the already posted answers indicate but you could also shorten to use `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN table1.text IS NULL THEN table2.numbers::text ELSE table1.text END AS newcolumn
```

Answer (score 5):

Problem is you are trying to add table1.text and table2.numbers into a single column. These two columns are two diff data types. try following

```
CASE WHEN table1.text IS NULL THEN CAST(table2.numbers AS VARCHAR(50)) ELSE table1.text END AS newcolumn
```

Answer (score 3):

The data type represented by `table2.numbers` and `table1.text` has to be the same, so it looks like in this case you'll need to `CAST` the value of `table2.numbers`

Answer (score 0):

Try `ISNULL`

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(table1.text) = 1 THEN table2.numbers ELSE table1.text END AS newcolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is pretty clear - the types of the two columns that may be used by the CASE statement aren't compatible.

Why would you think that trying to use values from two columns of different types would not cause problems? You may be creating a new column in the result set, but it still has to have a type and that has to match all the potential values.

It may be possible in a lot of cases for it to infer the type, but that's risky and may not necessarily be the choice that you want it to make, so it's better for it to force you to make the decision. You'll need to modify the type of one or the other columns in the CASE statement.